# Как проверить работает ли proguard?

Tags: java, android, gradle, build, proguard

Вот я подключил в градле библиотеку которая как я понял из описания будет удалять из моего `apk` файла все что не используется в проекте.

У меня в добавлены такие строки

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Но метод `getDefaultProguardFile` подчеркивает и пишет, что не может распознать его... Я загуглил и понял, что это проблема существует...

Попробовал способ который рекомендуют

```
"File" -> "Invalidate Caches..."
```

Но для меня это не сработало. Я так понимаю, что сейчас `proguard` вообще не работает...

Подскажите что сделать, чтоб это работало правильно?

Если кстати сделать так

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true

//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
//                    'proguard-rules.pro'

        proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

То ничего не подчеркивает, но как в таком случае проверить работает или нет?

Comment: В eclipse работет точно. Может надо указать путь файлу proguard-android-optimize.txt

Comment: @OlegA Есть идеи как это сделать? Я вообще не уверен, что этот файл существует...

Comment: @OlegA и как можно проверить работает или нет? Размер `apk` файла должен быть меньше?

Comment: ну что значит "меньше", у вас там куча не используемых классов? Я прогуард юзаю для обфускации. А проверить можно взяв, например JaDX, или еще какой-нибудь декомпилятор и глянуть что там в нутри получилось. Файл proguard-android-optimize.txt лежит в /sdk/tools/proguard

Comment: @OlegA А можете еще подсказать... Вот я взял декомпилятор `Dexplorer` открыл свое приложение, а там вообще классы никакие не открываются, из доступных только какой то класс `AppInfo` хотя у меня нет этого класса... Манифест доступен и `drawable` ресурсы... Что это может означать? Я так понимаю, что это как раз настройки `proguard` ограничивают доступ к `java` файлам?

Answer (score 1):

**Изменение #1**

`Но метод getDefaultProguardFile подчеркивает и пишет, что не может распознать его... Я загуглил и понял, что это проблема существует...`

Насколько я понимаю ваше *"подчеркивает"*, вы имеете в виду сообщение типа "cannot resolve symbol". Это нормально для Gradle! Изучу Ваш вопрос и чуть позже дополню ответ

**Изменение #0**

То, что у вас закомменчено есть файл настроек proguard, где вы указываете по какому принципу необходимо ему работать. (Какие библиотеки пропускать, где не учитывать варнинги и т.д.). Чтобы проверить, работает он или нет, необходимо его во первых включить (а он у вас включён), и указать файл настроек, а во вторых попытаться скомпилировать программу и собрать .apk. Если .apk собрался успешно - я вас поздравляю! Если нет, то изучите, какие логи вам прислал gradle и попытайтесь что то изменить (обычно, ошибки связаны с использованием библиотек).

Comment: Так дело в том, что файл и раньше компилился, все работает... У меня просто возник вопрос так как я обратил внимание на то, `getDefaultProguardFile` показывает что не распознается этот метод... Я сейчас закоментил эту строку и поставил другую и все так же компилиться без ошибок. Я поэтому и хочу проверить он действительно работает? Так как в первый раз ошибок тоже не было, но метод не распознавался - наверняка он не работал.

Comment: Я вот дополнил в комментариях к вопросу еще ответ, исходя из него правильно я понимаю?